# How to add a button to the column of ng-grid using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have tried to create a ng-grid with a button added to one its columns but I didn't get any idea that how to add a button to the column of ng-grid. Can anyone help me to add a button to the column of ng-grid using AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a custom template to the coulmnDef's cellTemplate property.

**cellTemplate**

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</button></span></div>
```

**columnDefs**

```
$scope.columnDefs = [
  {
    field:'name', displayName:'Name'
  }, 
  { 
    field:'age', displayName:'Age',editableCellTemplate:self.editableCellTempate ,enableCellEdit:true
  },
  {
    displayName:'Edit',
    cellTemplate: 'cellTemplate.html'
  }
]
```

**gridOptions**

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs 
};
```

**Example:** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/q74wc9?p=preview)